Golang Segmentio Getting half partitions while Consumer Group Migration
I am using github.com/segmentio/kafka-go lib.
My service is hosted on Kubernetes cluster and my use case is, I have one consumer group as C1, which is consuming messages from topic T1 which has 70 partitions. I have fetched the latest committed offsets for topic T1 by the consumer C1 for all the 70 partitions.
Now I have created a new, dynamic, consumer group for example as C2. So, as per my approach, I have committed offsets for all the 70 partitions and now I will fetch the assigned partitions for the particular pod of the new consumer group i.e. C2 and the seek and set the offsets of the assigned partitions as per old consumer C1.
So I am using group.Next() for getting the generation and from that I am fetching the assigned partitions for the particular pod of the C2. But here I am getting only half of partitions i.e. 35 partitions.
Any solve on this?
The new consumer group i.e. C2 should return all the 70 partition as assigned partitions for that particular topic T1.

Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [ask] and how to post a [example]. Thanks!

You show very little code, so it's hard to tell.
If the groups have the same ID, they are considered the same group, as far as Kafka is concerned. So it may be that you have two customers C1 and C2 in the same group.
What you see would be then be an effect of rebalancing triggered by a new customer joining the group.
